# Why html page isn't fit to 100%?

Tags: html, css, dom

Whenever i want to make a html page i have problem with this, why html page is less than 100%? Let me explain in example:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
          html
          {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
          }
          body
          {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          .row
          {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;  
          }
          .col-1
          {
            width: 10%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: inline-block;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
          <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Why last div comes to next line? With all width 10% means we can add 10 div in row, but in real world it doesn't happen?! I checked all margins, padding, borders but i didn't see anything. Could you tell me why this happens?

Comment: `display:inline-block` calculates distance of between two box as a space(&nbsp;). You can see it through adding border to `col-1`

Comment: Just use `float:left`

Comment: or, `<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!--
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>` (as <div class="col-1">...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give `display: inline-block;` it generates spaces in-between them. Use the same code this way:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div><!--
  --><div class="col-1">Some text</div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/xorahifipe**

You can also use `float: left`, but you need to give `overflow: hidden;` to the parent, or clear it somehow. With your original example, `float` works this way:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;    /* This is not necessary */
  margin: 0 auto; /* This is not necessary */
  padding: 0;     /* This is not necessary */
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.col-1 {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0;      /* This is not necessary */
  padding: 0;     /* This is not necessary */
  float: left;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/daruzepiqa/1**

Comment: You right, but why? You added a comment at the end of lines. Why html changes with comments?

Comment: @train_fox Comments are not seen as anything by HTML. If you notice, the comments eliminate the spaces. It is same as giving `<div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>`. Do you understand the logic now?

Comment: Yes, i see. Thank you.

Comment: @train_fox Gave the `float` version too. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `display:inline-block` creates white-space in the html...

you could change the `display:inline-block` to `float:left`

see https://jsfiddle.net/z0cc6fp7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can `float` the `divs` instead of using `inline-block` to get the effect you want.

```css
      html, body
      {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .row
      {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;  
      }
      .col-1
      {
        width: 10%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
      }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
      <div class="col-1">Some text</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I know about float, but i wants to use inline-block. but thanks for your reply.

Comment: May I ask why it matters?

Comment: In some place you need to use inline-block instead of using float. As my experience float will change my style. i use float rarely. Is there any benefits to use float instead of inline-block?

Comment: Well, for one, you don't have to deal with the extra spaces or add extra, unnecessary code to your html.  What do you mean "change my style"?

Comment: every tag and element has its usage. You can't just use one instead of other because is easier. You must know how they works.

Comment: Of course that's true.  But in your case, using float would be the right way to do it.  You have added extra, unnecessary tags because it is easier, not because it is right.  But it's fine either way.  It works for you and that's all that matters.